# How to only update one value in a nested dictionary with deepcopy

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

I am making an adjacency list to eventually make a graph of cities and the distance between them. To do so, the data structure in general looks like this after initialization:

```
my_dict = { 'city1': {'v1': -1, 'v2': -1, 'v3': -1},
            'city2': {'v1': -1, 'v2': -1, 'v3': -1},
            'city3': {'v1': -1, 'v2': -1, 'v3': -1}
          }
```

and so on.
Now that it's initialized, I began to read in the data and store it in the dict. line_list is the split line from my CSV file that contains two adjacent cities and a distance (i.e. (Boston, Charleston, 280)) The issue I'm running into is whenever I do  `my_dict['city1']['actual_name'] = line_list[2]` it creates that new key and value in every single city, rather than just city1. I read a lot online about the fact that I'm overriding the memory because of how python passes variables. The fix that comes up is to use copy or deep copy but no matter where I try to make the copy in my code or adjust the value it still ends up changing every value. Line 2 shows the most recent spot I've made the copy, I have also tried to do
'''

```
the_dict = {}
    for cit in my_dict:
        the_dict[cit] = copy.deepcopy(my_dict)
```

However, that didn't work. I've also tried making a copy of the whole dict before going into the conditional which didn't work.

```
    if my_dict[line_list[0]].get("v1", -2) == -1:
        my_dict[line_list[0]][line_list[1]] = deepcopy(line_list[2])
       # my_dict[line_list[0]][line_list[1]] = line_list[2]
    elif my_dict[line_list[0]].get("v1", -2) == -2:
        if my_dict[line_list[0]].get("v2", -2) == -1:
            my_dict[line_list[0]][line_list[1]] = my_dict[line_list[0]].pop("v2")
            my_dict[line_list[0]][line_list[1]] = line_list[2]
        elif my_dict[line_list[0]].get("v2", -2) == -2:
            if my_dict[line_list[0]].get("v3", -2) == -1:
                my_dict[line_list[0]][line_list[1]] = my_dict[line_list[0]].pop("v3")
                my_dict[line_list[0]][line_list[1]] = line_list[2]
    # CHECK IF THE EDGE YOU JUST ADDED HAS THE RECIPROCAL
    if my_dict[line_list[1]].get("v1", -2) == -1:
        my_dict[line_list[1]][line_list[0]] = my_dict[line_list[1]].pop("v1")
        my_dict[line_list[1]][line_list[0]] = line_list[2]
```

This is happening after line 2, I know the code looks rough but where would I have to make a copy in order to only add it to a certain city?

Comment: Most likely you have inserted the same dictionary many times into the outer dictionary, instead of creating a new instance for each city.

Comment: The first code you have shown using `deepcopy` looks decent (except the wrong indentation) – what do you mean by "that didn't work"? Please show a [mre] demonstrating the issue despite `deepcopy` being used.

Comment: Maybe you meant to copy `my_dict[cit]`?!

Comment: @mkrieger1 when that line is executed, "{Arad" : 75} is correctly inserted, but its inserted into every key in the outer dictionary (every city) instead of just city1

Comment: what I have in the post results in {'Arad' : {'v1': -1, 'v2': -1, 'v3': -1, 'Zerind': '75'}, 'Bucharest': {'v1': -1, 'v2': -1, 'v3': -1, 'Zerind': '75'} .... } and so on, with the zerind 75 in every city rather than just the one. What I'd like is  {'Arad' : {'v1': -1, 'v2': -1, 'v3': -1, 'Zerind': '75'}, 'Bucharest': {'v1': -1, 'v2': -1, 'v3': -1} .... }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mre].